# The default mathematics fonts

Tags: fonts

In math mode, LaTeX uses a different font for expressions such as `\max` than it would just for just `max`. Is there a way to keep this different usages of fonts, but change the font for expressions such as `\max` to something that is different than the default font for text?

Comment: `\max` is an operator definition with comes down to `\operator@font`

Comment: The question as it is stated is too broad; in order to get meaningful instructions, you should be more specific about the fonts you would like to use for the various types of entity that can occur in a mathematical formula (operators, variables, numbers…).  The answer to the question as it is currently formulated is “yes”. :-)

Comment: I tried to put \operator@sffamily in my preamble, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-assign the font for the `operators` alphabet, but note that includes digits and some punctuation by default:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{cmr} {bx}{it}
\begin{document}


$a + \max(1,2)$ max

\end{document}
```

It is of course possible to change the settings for digits, but it depends what you do want, and the more changes you make the more chance that the document is incompatible with some other math package.

You can also redefine `\operator@font` which is the font used by `\max` but that requires a slight dance as math font commands are defined to take an argument that isn't wanted here, but for example to use `\mathsf`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\operator@font{%
  \mathsf{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam}\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\tmp}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


$a + \max(1,2)$ max

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this would change the font of the text in a fraction.

Comment: @user109871 not `\frac{a}{b}` but it would probably change more than you intend, but your question wasn't too clear about exactly what you wanted to change, the command shown is the most literal interpretation of the question, it reassigns the operator font

Comment: @user109871 added a second mechanism